# Python complete search in one pass function

Tags: python, search, iteration

I am writing a program that takes in a list of start and end times for farmers milking cows and determines both the longest time where >=1 cow is being milked and the longest time where no cows are being milk.

In it, I've tried using this function. It's an exercise on complete search, but this isn't fast enough when there's a lot of data (I think because there are n^2 iterations).

`timesIS` is simply a list of the times in increasing start order, and `timesDE` is a list of the same times by decreasing end. `timeIndex` is the position from which to start. For the longest interval of milking, my program later does this for every index and returns the longest interval.

While still keeping to a complete search, how can I make this more efficient (switch to something closer to n passes, perhaps)?

```
def nextCease(TimesIS, timesDE, timeIndex):
    latestTime = TimesIS[timeIndex][1]
    for j in range (0, len(timesDE)):
        for i in range (0, len(timesDE)):
            if timesDE[i][0]<=latestTime and timesDE[i][1]>=latestTime:
                latestTime = timesDE[i][1]
        if latestTime == timesDE[0][1]:
            return latestTime
            break
    return latestTime
```

Here's a small piece of data input (first line is just the number of farmers):

```
6
100 200
200 400
400 800
800 1600
50 100
1700 3200
```

I *think* this is a minimal, complete, and verifiable example:

```
from operator import itemgetter
times = [[100,200], [200,400], [400,800], [800,1600], [50,100], [1700,3200]

def nextCease(TimesIS, timesDE, timeIndex):
    latestTime = TimesIS[timeIndex][1]
    for j in range (0, len(timesDE)):
        for i in range (0, len(timesDE)):
            if timesDE[i][0]<=latestTime and timesDE[i][1]>=latestTime:
                latestTime = timesDE[i][1]
        if latestTime == timesDE[0][1]:
            return latestTime
            break
    return latestTime

timesIS = sorted(times[:], key=itemgetter(0)) #increasing starttimes
timesDE = sorted(times[:], key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True) #decreasing endtimes

longestIntervalMilk = 0
for i in range (0, len(times)):
    interval = nextCease(timesIS, timesDE, i) - timesIS[i][0]
    if interval > longestIntervalMilk:
        longestIntervalMilk = interval

longestIntervalNoMilk = 0
latestFinish = 0
for i in range (0, len(times)):
    latestFinish = nextCease(timesIS, timesDE, i)
    timesIS2 = timesIS[:]
    while(timesIS2[0][0] < latestFinish):
        nextStartExists = True
        del timesIS2[0]
        if timesIS2 == []:
            nextStartExists = False
            break
    if nextStartExists == True:
        nextStart = timesIS2[0][0]
        longestIntervalNoMilk = nextStart - latestFinish

print(str(longestIntervalMilk) + " " + str(longestIntervalNoMilk) + "\n"))
```

EDIT: In the meantime, I wrote up this. It gives the wrong output for a very long list (it's 1001 lines so I won't reprint it here, but you can find it at http://train.usaco.org/usacodatashow?a=iA4oZAAX7KZ) and I'm confused as to why:

```
times = sorted(times[:], key=itemgetter(0))

def longestMilkInterval(times):
    earliestTime = times[0]
    latestTime = times[0][1]
    interval = 0
    for i in range (1, len(times)):
        if times[i][1] > latestTime and times[i][0] <= latestTime:
            if times[i][1] - earliestTime[0] > interval:
                interval = times[i][1] - earliestTime[0]
                latestTime = times[i][1]
        else:
            earliestTime = times[i]
            latestTime = times[i][1]
            print(earliestTime)
    return interval

def longestNoMilkInterval(times):
    earliestTime = times[0][1]
    interval = 0
    for i in range (0, len(times)):
        if times[i][0] >= earliestTime:
            if times[i][0] - earliestTime > interval:
                interval = times[i][0] - earliestTime
                break
        else:
            earliestTime = times[i][1]
    return interval
```

Output should be `912 184` (>=1 cow, 0 cow).

Comment: yes, using `bisect` to search in a sorted list of values. But we could help with a [mcve]. Without data, there's no way one can optimize your code.

Comment: Thanks! I've posted some more stuff and now I'm reading the article and will do my best.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I forgot to tag you, sorry.

Comment: no need when answering directly. So I have read it.

Comment: Ah right, I see.

Comment: no, this isn't a [mcve] because you're opening a file that we don't have. Try to make your example hold in a python code without any dependencies.

Comment: Apologies - hopefully the edited version is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very straightforward approach which does it in one pass, including a sort, so the complexity would be `O(n*logn)`.

```
# Part 1: transform to tuples (start_time, typ)
items = []
for start, end in times:
    items += [(start, 's'), (end, 'e')]
items = sorted(items)

# Part 2: compute max durations where 0 or 1+ cows are being milked
max_0_cows = max_1plus_cows = 0

last_intersection_time = items[0][0] # starting with first cow milk time
nof_cows_milked = 1

for i, (start_time, typ) in enumerate(items[1:], 1):
    if items[i-1][0] == start_time and items[i-1][1] != typ:
        continue
    if i+1 < len(items) and items[i+1][0] == start_time and items[i+1][1] != typ:
        continue

    if typ == 's':
        nof_cows_milked += 1
    elif typ == 'e':
        nof_cows_milked -= 1

    # check if we cross from 1+ -> 0 or 0 -> 1+
    if (typ, nof_cows_milked) in (('e', 0), ('s', 1)):
        duration = start_time - last_intersection_time
        if nof_cows_milked == 1:
            max_0_cows = max(max_0_cows, duration)
        if nof_cows_milked == 0:
            max_1plus_cows = max(max_1plus_cows, duration)
        last_intersection_time = start_time

print("Max time 0 cows: {}, Max time 1+ cows: {}".format(max_0_cows, max_1plus_cows))
```

1. Building of `items`: It puts the start/end itervals into a list of tuples `(start_time, typ)` so we can traverse the list and if we see a `s` a new cow is being milked and `e` then a cow is stopped being milked. This way we can have a counter `nof_cows_milked` at any time which is the basis for getting the "max time 0 cows milked" and "max time 1+ cows milked"
2. The actual longest-time-finder checks for all the transitions from 0 -> 1+ cows milked or 1+ cows -> 0 cows milked. In the first 4 lines it filters out the cases when two adjacent itervals (one farmer stops when the other farmer starts) It keeps track of those times with `last_intersection_time` and compares the duration to the max duration of `max_0_cows` and `max_1_plus_cows`. Again, this part is not very pretty, maybe there are more elegant ways to solve that.

> [my algorithm] gives the wrong output [...] and I'm confused as to why

Your algorithm basically just checks for the longest interval of a single tuple, but doesn't check for overlapping or adjacent tuples.

Take these intervals as an visual example:

[image]

Your code just finds the interval G-H, whereas you need to find C-F. You somewhere need to keep track of how many cows are milked in parallel, so you need at least the `nof_of_cows_milked` counter as in my code example.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still fairly new to Python, so could you possibly explain what the block starting from line 10 is doing? (Might be in your edit - I'm just getting my head around it. If so, please ignore this.)

Comment: @PeterW: I completed the explanation now, hope you understand, I'm back in ~1.5h

Comment: I've looked at the code. The problem (which you weren't to know from my example) is that it's not quite that simple. For example,
300 1000,
700 1200,
1500 2100 would give the wrong output, because there can be overlaps where end[i]!=start[i+1]

Comment: @PeterW: the code should cover that scenario as well, but there was a bug, I fixed it now

Comment: thank you for that; I'll look at it now. I've added to the bottom of my post some code I wrote in the meantime. I've been looking at this problem so long I'm not really sure why it's not working with some inputs. Any ideas?

Comment: @PeterW I ran my algorithm against your data set and it outputs the correct solution

Comment: I also added a section on why your algorithm does not work

Comment: @PeterW: I've simplified the script so it does it all in just one pass and the filtering out of adjacent intervals should be clearer now as well (I dropped the building of the `items_reduced` list)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Much appreciated. My programming / algorithmic skills (if they ever existed) are rusty from years of nonuse so thanks for your patience.