# Remove both adjacent tuples from lists

Tags: python, list

Given this list:

```
[(1, 's'), (2, 'e'), (2, 's'), (3, 'e')]
```

This is a representation of potentially overlapping intervals, e.g. `1 --> 2` and `2 --> 3`, I've brought it into this representation for easier processing (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48112301/119861) for context)

I'd like to remove the pair `(2, 'e')` -- `(2, 's')` because the end (`e`) of the one interval is at the same number (`2`) as start (`s`) of the next interval. So the result should be

```
[(1, 's'), (3, 'e')]
```

And would represent `1 --> 3`.

**Edit**: It's also possible that the intervals are overlapping, e.g. `1-->4` and `2-->3`. That would be represented in this list of tuples (Note that the list is already sorted): `[(1, 's'), (2, 's'), (3, 'e'), (4, 'e')]`. In this case nothing needs to be done as no two tuples share the same number.

I've come up with this reduce:

```
import functools
functools.reduce(lambda l,i: l[:-1] if i[0] == l[-1][0] and i[1] != l[-1][1] else l + [i], a[1:], [a[0]])
```

Are there nicer ways to achieve that?

Comment: And what should happen if the list is just `[(1, 's'), (2, 'e'), (2, 's')]`?

Comment: That's not possible, as by precondition 's' and 'e' need to be balanced

Comment: `[(1, 's'), (2, 'e'), (2, 's'), (2, 'e')]`?

Comment: yes, that's possible

Comment: Ok so how should this be handled? Should it just be `[(1, 's'), (2, 'e')]`?

Comment: Yes. Always adjacent end and starts should be removed. I see, this would invalidate Ajax1234's answer

Comment: What about actually overlapping intervals rather than adjacent intervals - e.g. `[(1, 's'), (3, 'e'), (2, 's'), (4, 'e')]`? Is that possible or valid input?

Comment: that's possible and valid, and will happen often, yes

Comment: @hansaplast one more - looks like your question assumes that if `item[n][1]=='s'` then `item[n+1][1]=='e'`; i.e. alternating `s` and `e` values. Is that correct and safe?

Comment: no, they don't need to be alternating always, see my edit in the question

Comment: You need to look for a different data structure. The problem you started with seems to have grown in complexity and I doubt any one line list-comprehension answer will prove an adequate enough solution to all the corner cases. Try interval tree

Comment: @smac89: I looked into [interval tree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree) but it does not offer a "merge adjacent" function, only "merge overlapping", can you provide a solution with interval tree?

Comment: @hansaplast Your edit doesn't completely clarify things. `Note that the list is already sorted. In this case nothing needs to be done as no two tuples share the same number.` In my earlier comment `[1,3,2,4]` is the correct result `[1,4]` or is it 'no action'?

Comment: it's "no action"

Comment: @hansaplast what if an end or starting point is shared? Like (1, 3) (2, 3) ? Or (1, 3) (2, 3) (3, 5)?

Comment: @PaulPanzer: that should result in (1, 3) (2, 3) and (1, 3)(2, 5)

Comment: Ok, to follow up on @KirkBroadhurst's comment `[1s] [3e] [2s] [4e] [3s] [5e]` would be legal and should result in `[1s] [2s] [4e] [5e]`? Meaning the end points to merge may be non-adjacent?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: whew, I was not aware that the question could lead to so much room for interpretation. I guess @smac89 is right that it needs some data structure or at least a commonly understood terminology to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` for a slightly longer (two lines), although more readable solution:

```
import itertools
def get_combinations(s):
   new_data = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(s, key=lambda x:x[0])]
   return [b[-1] for i, [a, b] in enumerate(new_data) if len(b) == 1 or len(b) > 1 and i == len(new_data) - 1]

print(get_combinations([(1, 's'), (2, 'e'), (2, 's'), (2, 'e')]))
print(get_combinations([(1, 's'), (2, 'e'), (2, 's'), (3, 'e')]))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 's'), (2, 'e')]
[(1, 's'), (3, 'e')]
```

Comment: the groupby and filter with `len()` is clever!

Comment: @hansaplast Please see my recent edit. I updated my answer to account for input similar to `[(1, 's'), (2, 'e'), (2, 's'), (2, 'e')]`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been toying with functional languages a lot lately, so this may read less Pythonic than some, but I would use a (modified) `itertools`'s `pairwise` recipe to iterate through by pairs

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)  # advance the second iterator
    return itertools.zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=(None, None))
```

then filter by which pairs don't match each other:

```
def my_filter(a, b):
    a_idx, a_type = a
    b_idx, b_type = b
    if a_idx == b_idx and a_type == "e" and b_type == "s":
        return False
    return True
```

Filter them yourself (because a naive `filter` will allow the "start" value to live since it pairs with the element ahead of it)

```
def filter_them(some_list):
    pairs = pairwise(some_list)
    acc = []
    while True:
        try:
            a, b = next(pairs)
            if my_filter(a, b):
                acc.append(a)
            else:
                next(pairs)  # skip the next pair
        except StopIteration:
            break
    return acc
```

Comment: `return not (a_idx == b_idx and a_type == "e" and b_type == "s")`

Comment: @smac89 shorter is not always better ;)

Comment: Depends what you mean by better. In terms of readability, the one I posted reads better

Comment: @smac89 oof if you say so. To me, a one-liner that returns the negation of a compound conditional does not a readable expression make, but of course YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I was tinkering about a "double continue" approach, and came up with this generator solution:

```
def remove_adjacent(l):
    iterator = enumerate(l[:-1])
    for i, el in iterator:
        if el[0] == l[i+1][0] and el[1] != l[i+1][1]:
            next(iterator)
            continue
        yield el
    yield l[-1]
```